# XBOX LIVE NuGet for UWP Games with DirectX: How to install the nuget?

Tags: directx, xbox-live

I have a problem and I was wondering if anyone could help me. In a nutshell:

- I applied to the Creators Program,
- I downloaded the SDK for XBOX Live,
- I upgraded my Visual Studio 2015 to the Update 3
- I installed the latest Windows 10 SDK, as instructed
- I created a brand new title, and
- I have a game as a UWP app using DirectX (I have not released, it is a brand new game that I was going to release at the Windows store eventually).

**My Problem is**:

- At the step where it says to link the XBOX Live NuGet, I just cannot find it on the list.
- I already browsed the entire SDK, and I cannot find any "readme" or "help" documentation that could guide me about how to install it.

**My Question is**:

- Does anyone know how I can install it, or would it be better if I go through the "Add a reference to the source code" instead?

Answer (score 1):

To add references to Xbox Live API NuGet packages in your project, in Visual Studio go to “Manage Nuget Packages”

You can enter “Xbox Live” (without quotes) in the search field in NuGet and you will find four variants of the Xbox Live API.

Choose the C++ for UWP Nuget package.

More information can be found at: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/games/xbox/docs/xboxlive/get-started/creators/getting-started-uwp-vs-creators